# Using JOOQ, how do you map an SQLException to a business exception?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jooq

I'm Using JOOQ, and would like to map certain SQLExceptions to business exceptions. The [exception handling](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-execution/exception-handling/) documentation page says:

> The following section about execute listeners documents means of overriding jOOQ's exception handling, if you wish to deal separately with some types of constraint violations, or if you raise business errors from your database, etc.

However, on [the page about execute listeners](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) has no practical examples.

I know I have to implement `ExecuteListener`'s method `exception(ExecuteContext)`, but it's unclear to me whether I should `throw` another exception from there, or instead use the `ExecuteContext.exception` method to override the existing exception. Eg.

```
@Override
public void exception(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.sqlException().getSQLState().equals("23503")) {
        throw new ForeignKeyViolationException("Foreign key violation", ctx.sqlException());
    }
}
```

Or:

```
@Override
public void exception(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.sqlException().getSQLState().equals("23503")) {
        ctx.exception(ForeignKeyViolationException("Foreign key violation", ctx.sqlException()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid, you'll have to do the work yourself. Here's why...

#### Using ExecuteListener won't work for you

The route of choosing an `ExecuteListener` for automatic and global translation of a `SQLException` is useful if you want alternative exceptions to jOOQ's [`DataAccessException`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/exception/DataAccessException.html) - e.g. Spring's [`DataAccessException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) for further processing ([example translator here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example/src/main/java/org/jooq/example/spring/exception/ExceptionTranslator.java)). It is not suitable for automatically rewiring a constraint violation exception to a specific "business exception", because the `ExecuteListener` (as a global actor) doesn't know in what context a constraint violation may have happened. There could be:

- Bugs causing constraint violations (e.g. you should have updated, rather than inserted)
- User errors causing constraint violations (e.g. the user submitted a form twice)
- Actual business rules causing constraint violations (e.g. check constraints)

You have to decide this for each query individually, I'm afraid. `ExecuteListener` only helps you rewire the technical part of exception handling.

#### Why does the manual mention "business errors"?

You've quoted the manual:

> or if you raise business errors from your database

These business errors might be user-defined errors that you raise from a database trigger, for instance, in case of which you won't be getting a constraint violation, but a meaningful business error directly from the database.

Comment: I should probably not have used the term "business exception" as I feel it has caused some confusion. I don't mean specific exceptions tied to business logic (eg. something like "BasketEmptyExcetion"), but rather exceptions for specific SQL errors (like a unique constraint of foreign key violation), so that they could be caught and handled more easily in the business code (rather than catching DataAccessException and comparing the SQL state in-place). But for illustration purposes, say I would want to throw a Spring DataAccessException, which of the two examples from my question is correct?

Comment: @Hexagone: In the specific case of translating exceptions to Spring DataAccessException, you could use the example exception translator here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example/src/main/java/org/jooq/example/spring/exception/ExceptionTranslator.java. I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Eder, that answers my question fully. Perhaps it would be handy if this example would be included somewhere in the documentation as well.

Comment: @Hexagone: It is referenced from this page: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring